# how to get update rows count in jdbctemplet Spring java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

```
int[][] updateCounts = jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(QueryConstant.UPDATE_MERCHANT_STATUS,merchantList,1,
           new ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter<Merchant>() {
           
           public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, Merchant merchant)
              throws SQLException {
              ps.setString(1, merchant.getMerchantId());                        
           }
        }); 
        
        int a=0;
        for(int[] i : updateCounts) {
            System.out.println(updateCounts.length+":COUNT:"+i[a]);
        }
        System.out.println(updateCounts[1][0]+":test:"+updateCounts[0][0]);
```

Query using in code for update: update merchant set flag='P' where merchant_id in('1111','2222','');

I have 3 different parameters and only two row are getting update as last value is blank.

I'm getting sysout as this:
3:COUNT:-2
3:COUNT:-2
3:COUNT:-2
-2:test:-2

How can i get count of only affected(updated) rows?

Answer (score 0):

With batch using prepared statement, -2 indicates that the operation is successful but the affected row count could not be determined.

Since you are using batch size of 1, do you need batch in the first place? Either statement can be used or batching can be ignored.